# Dynamic subseting a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a fixed no numeric columns and an arbitrary numeric columns like this:

```
s <- data.frame(A=c("a","b","c"),B=c(1,2,3), C=c(24,15,2))
```

I also have two vectors with the same length of the number of numeric columns defining the min and max values for every column.

```
min <- c(2,10)
max <- c(3,30)
```

I want to subset the dataframe with all the rows than have column B between 2 and 3, and column C between 10 and 30. Like this:

```
s <- s[s$B >= min[1] & s$B <= max[1] & s$C >= min[2] & s$C <= max[2],]
```

To subset the dataframe for an arbitrary number of numeric columns right now I use a for statment:

```
for(i in 1:length(min))
  s <- s[s[,i+1] >= min[i] & s[,i+1] <= max[i],]
```

This do the job but is very slow. I have around 20 columns and 150K rows in the data frame.

There is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically, like this?

```
s <- data.frame(A=sample(letters,100,T),B=sample(1:4,100,T), C=sample(2:40,100,T))
# larger dataframe

min <- c(2,10)
max <- c(3,30)

  filt<-rowSums(
    sapply(1:length(min),function(x){   # for each item in min (or max)
    s[,x+1]>=min[x] & s[,x+1]<=max[x]   # create a T/F vector
    })
  )==length(min)                        # this returns T for cases where all criteria are met

  s[filt,]  # this applies your filter to s
```